# VS 2008 suddenly can't start debugging session

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging

I am having great problems running the application in the debugger from Visual Studio 2008.

When I'm using vshost.exe, it says:

[image]

And when vshost.exe is turned of, it simply states:

[image]

Interesting thing about it is that when i do use vshost, debugger is actually started and breakpoint is hit on the first line of the Main().

I tried:

- rebuilding the project(s)
- removing .ncb, .suo, .user for the projects
- repairing Visual Studio 2008
- changing the build architecture for the project

...  no help there...

Any experience in (trouble)shooting that?

More info: some projects DO work, and one that I have to work on, does not.

I have some ideas such as:

- trying to create NEW project, add thing by thing to it and see at what point it will start to miss behave
- work it other way around, delete project by item by item to see when it will (if it will) be working OK again.

EDIT (for google, as I see that there are many similar questions on the web):

Errors:

> Error while trying to run project: Unable to start debugging.

and

> Error while trying to run project: Unable to start program '....\PlayKontrol.exe'

Comment: If you start an empty project, does that work right now? If you run the application *without* debugging, does it work?

Comment: New project works OK, and running it without debugging also works OK.  Let me repeat, when I F5 the app, and have host process ON, it shows the error, but RUNS the debugger (breakpoint is HIT)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try upgrading your Visual Studio to Service pack 1, if you haven't already.

Comment: That did it.  Thanks for the idea one more time.

Answer (score 1):

Did you restarted your computer? You never know how windows will react to that :).
Also be sure there aren't any keys stuck, like the ctrl or windows key.
Note that the key does not have to be visually stuck, it can be stuck for visual studio and not for the explorer.

Comment: Thank you, I tried to restart it for several times.  No help there.

Answer (score 1):

The most common source of sudden problems like this is corruption of one of the data files that vs uses to cache information between builds.

You've tried a clean build, but this won't delete everything. A real clean build is: quit vs, delete bin, obj, debug, release folders, delete all generated files in the root - primarily ncb. Do the same for any locally built libraries that you're project references.

The easiest way to do this is if you have the code in source control, as you can rename away your entire code folder and then force a get of all the source.

You often need to do all of these things in one hit to clear the problem.

Less frequently, a reinstall of vs will sort things out (although this sounds unlikely in your case if it is only one project that breaks)

Also think carefully about anything you might have installed just prior to it failing... And remember that some install effects may not occur until the next reboot so it could be days ago. A particular cause of this are automatic windows updates and trial versions of things like the vs 11 beta.

Comment: Thanks, I'll do that one more time after SP reinstall, and try exporting from SVN to do a clean rebuild.  Only recent install that I had was VS2010.  Maybe it broke VS2008 a little.

Answer (score 1):

You might try running the application from outside of VS, but have a line of code that looks like this:  `Debugger.Launch();` where you want your first breakpoint.

Comment: Thanks, good idea, however, I can debug anyway, just have to OK the error dialog that I have.  However, I would not like to use any workarounds here, since who-knows-what might be broken...